# Multi-threaded Producer Performance when KafkaTemplate autoFlush set to true?

Tags: spring-kafka

KafkaTemplate has an autoFlush option which flushes every time it sends a message.

```
/**
 * Send the producer record.
 * @param producerRecord the producer record.
 * @return a Future for the {@link RecordMetadata}.
 */
protected ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> doSend(final ProducerRecord<K, V> producerRecord) {
    if (this.transactional) {
        Assert.state(inTransaction(),
                "No transaction is in process; "
                    + "possible solutions: run the template operation within the scope of a "
                    + "template.executeInTransaction() operation, start a transaction with @Transactional "
                    + "before invoking the template method, "
                    + "run in a transaction started by a listener container when consuming a record");
    }
    final Producer<K, V> producer = getTheProducer();
    if (this.logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
        this.logger.trace("Sending: " + producerRecord);
    }
    final SettableListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> future = new SettableListenableFuture<>();
    producer.send(producerRecord, new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exception) {
            try {
                if (exception == null) {
                    future.set(new SendResult<>(producerRecord, metadata));
                    if (KafkaTemplate.this.producerListener != null
                            && KafkaTemplate.this.producerListener.isInterestedInSuccess()) {
                        KafkaTemplate.this.producerListener.onSuccess(producerRecord.topic(),
                                producerRecord.partition(), producerRecord.key(), producerRecord.value(), metadata);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    future.setException(new KafkaProducerException(producerRecord, "Failed to send", exception));
                    if (KafkaTemplate.this.producerListener != null) {
                        KafkaTemplate.this.producerListener.onError(producerRecord.topic(),
                                producerRecord.partition(),
                                producerRecord.key(),
                                producerRecord.value(),
                                exception);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally {
                if (!KafkaTemplate.this.transactional) {
                    closeProducer(producer, false);
                }
            }
        }

    });
    if (this.autoFlush) {
        flush();
    }
    if (this.logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
        this.logger.trace("Sent: " + producerRecord);
    }
    return future;
}
```

This seems nice for those who want to make every send request synchronous.

But when used with DefaultKafkaProducerFactory which produces singleton Producer object, all thread-local producer of KafkaTemplate points to same single Producer, thus sharing send queue.

In multi-threaded web environment, every thread must wait for the messages not only from its own but all the messages other threads already sent.

I think it's bad idea not only performance-wise but also availability-wise, because in a situation some of the Kafka brokers went down, it's highly likely that all the threads wanting to send messages hang when some of them do not need to.

Am I correct? Shouldn't there be a comment warning this on any guides or documents or something?

Comment: Good question. This could be a bottleneck. I wonder why Apache did it so stupidly. However this can be fixed easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think the JavaDocs are pretty clear...

```
/**
 * Create an instance using the supplied producer factory and autoFlush setting.
 * <p>
 * Set autoFlush to {@code true} if you have configured the producer's
 * {@code linger.ms} to a non-default value and wish send operations on this template
 * to occur immediately, regardless of that setting, or if you wish to block until the
 * broker has acknowledged receipt according to the producer's {@code acks} property.
 * @param producerFactory the producer factory.
 * @param autoFlush true to flush after each send.
 * @see Producer#flush()
 */
```

What more do you think is needed?

Comment: I found people think autoFlush is per-thread synchronization.

What I assumed is, with DefaultKafkaProducerFactory, one producer gets shared across every thread, so it's per-application synchronization. send() requests may not return even after the request itself already completed, when other send requests exist.

There should be comment pointing that, people should wait for Future object and set linger.ms to smaller value, instead of setting autoFlush to true. Especially in production environment with synchronous web frameworks like Spring.

Are my assumptions right??